# How do I automatically generate XAML for datagrid columns?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, wpfdatagrid

There used to be a way to have Visual Studio create XAML for the DataGrid columns based on the current data context. (no I'm not talking about the AutoGenerateColumns feature). It has been a long time since I've done this and now I can no longer find the option in the designer. (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: Actually from the way you describe it, it sounds exactly like the AutoGenerateColumns. Do you mean, you used the properties window, and then added the Columns through a design component, or how do you think you achieved this in Visual Studio 2013? Is it just your intention not to write the Xaml manually?

Comment: While this is writing the xaml manually, the tool I used will at least stub it out for you to save some typing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this was part of the wpfToolkit 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vinsibal/2008/11/07/wpf-datagrid-design-time-walkthrough/